# Is heat supposed to bounce on an insulator or slowly go through it?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a simple flat electric heater at home, fixed on a wall. 50% of the energy is absorbed by the wall !!

What would happen if I put some isolation material between the heater and the wall ?

Would the 50% of energy BOUNCE BACK and heats the air in the room ?

**or**

Would isolation just make the heat go slower to the wall, but it will get there eventually, keeping 50% energy loss ?

[image: heat possibilities]

Comment: My house has a sheet of aluminum foil behind each radiator to reflect the heat back into the room. The more (and/or better quality) insulation you put on the wall directly behind the heater, the less heat is absorbed by the wall and is available to heat the room. You won't be 95% better off though it should save some money on your heating bills

Comment: @AcidJazz: maybe there is a misunderstanding. imagine that the heat produced is not made of radiations. my question is : will insulation absorb the heat too ? or will it make it "bounce" ?

Comment: Sorry about that, foil will make the heat bounce back into the room, for sure and insulation will not so much make it bounce back as instead it acts to reduce the amount of the outside coldness that comes through the wall and thereby reduces the amount of the room heat.  Actually, behind some rads you will have a foil reflector with a bit of insulation stuck onto the back of it, next to the wall, to try to minimise the heat loss in the best way.

Comment: And the heat **is** made of radiation, it's packets of infrared radiation (photons). That's why the foil works, it's a mirror for infra red photons, the same idea as why a bathroom mirror will reflect visible light photons, light rays in other words.

Comment: @AcidJazz Heat is also particles that vibrate and transmit vibrations to other particles.

Answer (score 1):

If you touch the outside wall, does it feel like touching a heater? I guess not, so therefore we know that you are not losing 50% of the energy through the wall, but maybe something like 5%.

The outside wall is cool, because the air gap and the wall are insulators. Adding more insulation reduces the conduction of heat through the insulators.

Comment: the outside wall has cold temperature coming from outside so it is a little in between room temperature and outside temperature.

I have edited my question to make it more understandable. Does (most of the) heat bounces back on an insulator or does it get through anyway, but slowly ?

Comment: Yes, heat bounces back. (By one insulator surface getting warm, and then heating the environment)

Comment: If your wall is made of metal, then the inside surface of the wall next to the heater becomes warm and warms the inside air, and the outside surface becomes equally warm and warms the outside air. I mean a heater shaped patch of the wall becomes warm.

Comment: Hey I just noticed that you lose more than 50% of the heat if the outside air is cooler than the inside air, and your wall is made of metal.

Comment: so what is your conclusion @user7027 ?

Comment: About 5% of the heat produced by the heater goes through the wall behind the heater. Adding insulation behind the heater results about 2.5% of the heat produced by the heater going through the wall behind the heater. (Assuming the wall is a normal wall)

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, we need to clear up what 'heat' is. "Heat" is not really a thing; it means nothing more than "energy transfer in some disorganized way". The two main modes of heating in this case are conduction (atoms in your heater warm up adjacent air atoms) and radiation (atoms in your heater emit infrared light). When we say something is a thermal insulator, we mean that it conducts heat slowly. Radiation bounces, while conduction doesn't.

In the case of conduction, it probably will make no difference as long as the outside of your heater isn't literally touching the wall. Sure, the air behind your heater will be warmed up a lot, but it'll quickly rise and spread out in the rest of the room (i.e. it'll convect).

In the case of radiation, it actually does make a difference. Except a conventional insulator won't work, because they only conduct slowly. What you really want is something visibly shiny, like a mirror or foil (infrared wavelengths are close to visible ones, so if something looks shiny it probably reflects infrared too).

I believe actual heaters use a mix of the two methods, so you'll get a modest (not 50%) increase if you use foil, and a tiny one if you use an insulator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the case of conduction, what happens if atoms are close to void ? if they don't have other atoms to whom they can convey  their vibration, then it doesn't vibrate back ?